# eclipse is not able to run my Junit test cases

Tags: java, gradle, junit, eclipse-luna

I am using JUnit4 library to test the java code.

I am running simple test case like below. However, I am getting the below eclipse error when run the below test case Junit. I am using the Jdk 1.8 and java compiler is also set to 1.8. Compare the run configurations which are same as other machine eclipse configurations working fine on it.

Please help

Error:

could not find or load main class :(.java:|.gradle:|.groovy:|)

```
   import org.junit.*;

    public class MyTestCase {

    @Test
    public void test(){
      fail("Not yet implemented")
    }
    }
```

Comment: How did you try to run it? It seems you tried to run it as a main class. You shouldn't. Right click and select something like "Run as -> JUnit test"

Comment: I did it run as junit only. I have tested the same test case so far without issues. I think today I have imported gradle project as existing project and after that my eclipse got some issue i guess but not able to figure out